# unexpected AST node: (

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

> unexpected AST node: ( near line 1, column 78 [SELECT w FROM
>   tech.return0er.donkeygo.dao.entity.WalkEntity w WHERE
>   ST_Within(w.start_point, ST_MakePolygon('LINESTRING(41.15294130710586
>   113.20090225705104, 41.15294130710586 115.97018471050012, 37.53742712587926 115.97018471050012, 37.53742712587926 113.20090225705104, 41.15294130710586 113.20090225705104)')) AND w.visibility=0 AND w.state=0 ORDER BY w.start_time DESC]

I don't know why this error happened, another query command is the same format

```
SELECT w FROM ${WalkEntity.TABLE_NAME} w WHERE ST_DistanceSphere(w.start_point, ST_MakePoint(?1, ?2)) <= ?3*1000
```

This command works fine.

Comment: JPQL != SQL. You're using SQL where JPQL is expected. Thats basically equivalent to compiling Java code with a C compiler.

Comment: So what should I do to make this query command works? I changed my query command as this link:https://gist.github.com/michael-simons/824ff17aebc1aa6fe4cf26a3fe795892